# "General error: 1366 Incorrect integer value" even though I have set validation to nullable

Tags: php, laravel-5

I get this error:
[image]

When I am trying to create and I am not filling the input for fixed_quantity

This is my store in my Controller(I have set fixed_quantity to nullable so it should be fine right?):

```
 $this->validate($request, [
        'name'                      => 'required',
        'description'               => 'required',
        'fixed_quantity'            => 'nullable',
        'max_increments'            => 'required|numeric|min:0',
    ]);

    DB::transaction(function () use ($request, $store, $variant) {

        $subscription_plan = new SubscriptionPlan([
            'store_id'                  => $store->uuid,
            'variant_id'                => $variant->uuid,
            'name'                      => $request->input('name'),
            'description'               => $request->input('description'),
            'max_increments'            => $request->input('max_increments'),
        ]);

        $subscription_plan->fixed_quantity = $request->input('fixed_quantity');

        $subscription_plan->save();
```

This is what is on my blade:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="fixed_quantity">Quantity</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="number" id="fixed_quantity" name="fixed_quantity" value="{{ old('fixed_quantity') }}"" placeholder="0">
</div>
```

Comment: What value is being stored? Can you check? Because if the input is number and it's empty, I think Laravel will try to set it as an empty string.

Comment: @Phiter it's just ' ' in the error since it doesn't get saved to the db.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look closely, the error is saying that it's trying to put `''` in the column.

Check if the input is empty and don't set it if it is.

```
if (!empty($request->input('fixed_quantity')))
    $subscription_plan->fixed_quantity = $request->input('fixed_quantity');
```

Comment: By the way, Laravel has an `ConvertEmptyStringsToNull` middleware which does exactly as the name says for each request parameter.

Answer (score 0):

try this

check fixed_quantity before insert

```
'fixed_quantity' => $request->has('fixed_quantity') ? $request->input('fixed_quantity') : NULL,
```

this `nullable` store as string on `integer field` thats why

```
'fixed_quantity'            => 'nullable',
```

Answer (score 0):

`nullable` means that `null` is an acceptable value, but you are passing it an empty string (`''`), which is not. Change your code to something like this:

```
$subscription_plan->fixed_quantity = !empty($request->input('fixed_quantity')) ? $request->input('fixed_quantity') : null;
```